# if not logged in redirect after 6 page counts?

Tags: php, redirect, count

I am trying to get this script to work properly but am not having any luck, please can someone show me what i need to do.

At the moment the script counts the number of times a page has been accessed and redirects the user to another page if the count reaches 6.

It should only redirect if the user is not logged in, but instead it is also redirecting users when they are logged in. Please can someone show me where im going wrong.

Thanks.

```
<?
    !session_id() ? session_start() : null;

    if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && empty($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
        verify_profile_visit_limit();
    }

    function verify_profile_visit_limit(){
        $free_profiles = array(99999,99998,99997,99996,99995,99994,99993);

        if(in_array($_GET["id"], $free_profiles)) return;

        if(! isset($_SESSION["page_access_count"])){
            $_SESSION["page_access_count"] = 1;
        }

        $_SESSION["page_access_count"]++;

        if($_SESSION["page_access_count"] > 6){
            header("Location: limit.php");
            exit();
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: I think the problem with your first line 
Replacing it with 
    session_start(); 
Might fix your problem because you are calling the function for the non logged users

Comment: no that still redirects the logged in users

Comment: Then check the value to zero also in the 2nd line

Answer (score 0):

Add an 'is logged in?' check to the pagecount check:

```
    if (($_SESSION["page_access_count"] > 6) && (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
```

if they're logged in, the check fails and they don't get redirected.